# Tesseract OCR with Python

Tags: python, text, tesseract, orc

i am looking for a way too get the text from the image below. I tried to use tesseract but the outputs weren't good at all (see code block below). Do i have to edit the picture to get a better output? What params should i use for tesseract? Or is there even a better way? Is Tesseract confused by the small icons?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynzsw.jpg)

```
TEAM 1 41 / 28 / 63

& ¢ 18 @) BanemBanem

v7 é 18 @ Feldwebel Nick

* 3 18 C) Eldijaner
6 & 15 ) MarkusLanz187

4 a a
be 18 = benjamin2436

TEAM 2 27 / 41 / 47

w 8 17 e) grummeldom
* 5 15 © Edelmann
é § 18 cB) BanemBanem
6 é 14 &) DefreezeLP
@ & 15 @ Berboinsens

72,105

BE Dwr w
WE MIS AE @
ZV we
BoQwD Bb
tore &
64,599
WEL See @
Soe Pew we
PRESS
LINEAR AD

25

418

4/2

417

413

413

/9

419

/9

43

‘7

168

302

209

44

161

198

138

274

42

227

14,298
22,143
12,554
9,925

13,185

13,462
12,096
16,722
8,588

13,731

BANS + OBJECTIVES

"yy y

usd dl ia
4,

V3 Gs,

8 2 1 5 0

BANS + OBJECTIVES

vf ie af
o %
```

I tried these commands for tesseract
`tesseract test2.png out3 digits`
`tesseract statsedit.png out.txt -l eng`

Answer (score 0):

In order for tesseract to make the OCR, you have to give it a well processed image (and the tune tesseract based on what you're trying to 'OCR').

Usually, `opencv-python` is the used library for making this pre-processing, by firstly converting it to a grayscale image, then applying a little blur, and finally thresholding it.
I'm pretty sure you can find on YouTube some kind of tutorials that show u step-by-step how to correctly pre-process an image, based on your use-case.